# jquery push container div vs class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a bit of jquery that goes as follows....

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // HTML markup implementation, overlap mode, push 3 DOM elements
    $( '#menu' ).multilevelpushmenu({
        containersToPush: [$( '#pushobj' ), $( '#pushthisobjalso' ), $( '#pushthisobjtoo' )]
    });
});
```

this is great but instead of pushing divs I want to push the entire body tag of my page.. Doing the obvious "#body" doesn't seem to work and here are a couple of examples of my incompetence.....

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // HTML markup implementation, overlap mode
    $( '#menu' ).multilevelpushmenu({
        containersToPush: [$( '#body' )],
```

Didn't work ... Also tried the class which is how it is structured on html `<body class="metro">`

so i tried this but it didn't work.....

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // HTML markup implementation, overlap mode
    $( '#menu' ).multilevelpushmenu({
        containersToPush: [$( '#body.metro' )],
```

hope this is concise enough , I really appreciate your pointers on here.

Comment: Why on earth do you want to put the whole body into your menu?

Comment: its not , it's identified by the function as the thing that is being moved when the menu changes shape

Comment: okay, have fun... you may run into issues where the menu moves with the body (because the menu is surely in the body). But seriously, look at https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: hah, fair point ..... i just wanted to move everything on the page accross when the menu comes out

Comment: i realised from reading selector documentation that you can do "*" for all elements ... i wonder if you could say all elements except the menu itself hmmmmm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // HTML markup implementation, overlap mode
    $( '#menu' ).multilevelpushmenu({
        containersToPush: [$( '#body .metro' )],
```

maintain space between id and class

Comment: what about if it just for something like a h1 tag.... thought it might be $('h1') but it doesn't seem to be

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do sounds like a ridiculously bad idea.

Nevertheless, the jQuery command to select the body tag would be `$("body")`. The hash that you are using tells jQuery to look for an element with the `id` of "body". So if your html were as below, your $("#body") would work because of the id:

```
<html>
  <body id="body">
  </body>
</html>
```

In the html below `$("#body")` selects the `<div>` (not the `<body>`!):

```
<body>
  <div id="body">
    <span class="foo">
      <a class="bar"></a>
    </span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Also:

`$(".foo")` selects the `<span>`
`$("a")` selects the `<a>`
`$("a.bar")` also selects the `<a>`

Take a look at https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: do you think i could just do this without having to specify the class metro ?

Comment: ...also if it was a class would it just be $(".something")

Comment: @havingagoatit yes it would

Answer (score 0):

To reference elements you can either do so via their ID (which begins with the # (hash tag)

```
$("#myID")
```

a class (which begins with a period)

```
$(".myClasss")
```

or the actual HTML element itself which is just the element.

```
$("body")
```